# find a regular expression

Tags: regular-language

find a regular expression for w such that it does not contain $ aab $ , where w is the strings of $a$'s and $b$'s .

ans: I know how to draw the same question with $ aab $ , but cant understand how to proceed for this question.

Comment: Every $a$ (except for any $a$'s at the end of the string) must be immediately followed by a $b$. You should be able to construct an r.e. that does that...

Answer (score 0):

There is an algorithm for converting a FA into a RE.  Since you said you can draw the FA, why not apply that algorithm?

[image: FA]